# How to utilize idle CPU cycles during WebService invocation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am invoking a web service, which displays the result in the UpdatePanel. The web sevice returns the result in approximately 30 sec. to 1 min. During this time interval I am currently displaying UpdateProgress Bar.

My goal is to utilize idle processor time & do some useful operation in foobar() method, out of following approach which one fits best in current scenario -

1. Call the web sevice asynchronously using BeginAsync keep doing other
   task until BeginAsync invokes its callback method.
2. Add webservice operation inside a thread, and use QueueUserWorkItem
   to enque this thread to a ThreadPool. (I will have to use WaitAny in
   this case, since as soon as webservice returns data, I need to
   terminate thread running foobar method.)
3. I wonder whether it is possible in asp.net to callback a method
   once UpdataProgress control gets triggered and terminate this, when
   this is done.

Comment: +1 for `utilize idle processor`